# How to check file content is already read in mule 4?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have placed one file test.txt in the test folder and reading this file using the read connector in mule4. I have created another file test1.txt with the same content as in test.txt. Now, I want to check the file content is already read or not. How can we achieve this in mule4?

Answer (score 0):

A flow can be triggered by File connector listener. You can configure it to move or delete a read file. Other than that, if you want to keep a record of the files processed you will need to store the names into a database. The connector doesn't keep a history.